# How to do MD5 with foreign characters?

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine, md5

So I am making my custom highscore board in mobile game, using unity engine.

I setup my mysql database, and bought highscore asset from store, it works, but only with english user name. So basically it send user's name, score to .php script.

But I want that script also can receive korean characters as user's nickname. My users will use korean characters too as nickname not only english characters.

How can I achieve this?

Here are codes.

------------------(Highscore.cs  at unity side)

```
WWWForm rsFm = new WWWForm();
            rsFm.AddField("name",name);   
        // at here name field, I want to receive korean characters as well.
            rsFm.AddField("tables",tables);
            rsFm.AddField("hash",GetHash(name));
            WWW rs = new WWW(registerUserURL,rsFm);
            yield return rs;
```

..................

```
string GetHash(string usedString){ //Create a Hash to send to server
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(usedString+secretKey);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++){
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
```

### }

### RegisterUser.php

```
<?php
include('ServerConnect.php');
$connection = Connect();//Attempt to Connect to MYSQL Server & DataBase

//Get variables from unity
$name = $_POST['name'];
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
$tables = $_POST['tables'];
//Security Check
$hash = $_POST['hash'];
if(CheckKey($hash,$name) == 'fail'){ //Check if hash is valid
    echo 'Security Failure'; exit;
```

### }

### ServerConnect.php

```
function CheckKey($hash,$name){  //Check weather Md5 hash matches
    global $secretKey; 
    $checkHash = md5($name.$secretKey);
    if(strcmp($checkHash,$hash) == 0){
        return 'pass'; //hash matches
    }else{
        return 'fail'; //hash failed
    }
```

### }

When I input korean character and send, console Result says "Security Failure" at above code.

Comment: Maybe you should encode tha inserted value before trying to hash it?

Comment: `byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(usedString+secretKey);`. Your C# code is using the wrong encoding.

Comment: Maybe you should hash the scores or equivalent together with the name and the salt, creating a proper checksum? If you hash only the name an user can sniff the name/hash and post using a different set of scores.

Comment: @OfirBaruch How to do it?

Comment: @Phylogenesis Then how should I revise?

Comment: @OdraEncoded What do you mean salt? and how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like a user has stated before, you are using the wrong encoding if you will be using out of ascii chars (the case for korean, japanese, etc). You should be using **Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes** instead of Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes, take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for the example function GetMd5Hash. If you run ASCII md5, a different md5 will be generated.

The "salt" is the secret key you are using. $secretKey in PHP and secretKey in C#. You should read a little about security if you dont know what salt is, because if you dont you'll think you created a secure(r) system and you havent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks !!! Change to UTF8 solves. and 'salt' is ah my custom secretkey, I set it.